# How to change the style of individual components of an SVG path?

Tags: svg

The following code assigns the colour green to all the three lines of the SVG path.

```html
<svg height="210" width="400">
          <path d="M 150 0 
                   L 75 200 
                   L 225 200  
                   L 150 0"
                fill ="none" stroke="green" stroke-width="3" />
       </svg>
```

Can I know how I can assign separate styles to each line?

Comment: you can't really. If you need different styles, use multiple paths.

Comment: I am generating a path based on user input. Generating a single "d" attribute programmatically seemed to be more convenient than generating multiple lines. Thank you @RobertLongson for letting me know that it is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to have multiple styles within a single SVG path.

Answer (score 2):

In this case the solution would be using 3 different lines:

```html
<svg height="210" width="400">
  <g stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="3" >
      <path d="M 150 0 
               L 75 200" stroke="green"/> 
      <path d="M75 200
               L 225 200" stroke="gold"/>  
      <path d="M225 200
               L 150 0" stroke="red"/>
   </g>
 </svg>
```

Comment: Thank you @enxaneta. I wanted to know if it is possible to have different styles within a path. I now understand that it is not possible.